# CreditCardDirectivesModule is not an NgModule

Tags: angular, npm

I am using following OS, npm and node version:

```
MacOS Sierra 
version 10.12.4 
npm 5.4.2

@angular/cli: 1.3.1
node: 8.0.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.6
@angular/common: 4.3.5
@angular/compiler: 4.3.5
@angular/core: 4.3.5
@angular/forms: 4.3.5
@angular/http: 4.3.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.5
@angular/router: 4.3.5
@angular/cli: 1.3.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.5
@angular/language-service: 4.3.5
```

I get the following error on attempt to "ng build --prod".

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'CreditCardDirectivesModule in 
/Users/c149/Documents/AngularSites/node_modules/ng2-cc-library/dist/directives.d.ts' 
imported by the module 'AppModule in /Users/c149/Documents/AngularSites/src/app/app.module.ts'. 
Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

Comment: can you show your `AppModule` and `CreditCardDirectivesModule`'s code?

Comment: According to the documentation on  ng2-cc-library page, you should move to their new version